# Functions always execute first during echo?

Tags: php

Is there any why I can write this code by calling `echo` once to get output as `hello Sam`?

This is the PHP code :

```
<?php  

    function moo() {
        echo 'Sam';
    }

    echo 'hello ' . moo();

?>
```

The output is `Samhello`
The parsing is `R to L`. I can achieve the desired output by writing `echo` on 2 separate lines as :

```
<?php  

    function moo() {
        echo 'Sam';
    }

    echo 'hello ';
    echo moo();

?>
```

but is there a way to do this in one line?

Comment: It's because you don't **return** any value!

Comment: @TamilSelvan That's what he is trying to do :)

Comment: Wow, people are always ready to downvote

Comment: You want to use `return` in the function not `echo`

Comment: When you use a function inside a string concat, the function will execute. What you want to do is to have the function actually return the value to where it was being called from (in your case inside the string concat) instead of just outputting the data when it was called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having the function `echo`, just have it return the string you want to print. Then let the caller decide what to do with it - in this case, `echo` it:

```
function moo() {
    return 'Sam';
}

echo 'hello ' . moo();
```

Edit: Adding explanation (not the author of the answer) rather than leaving comment.

The difference between a "return" and an inline concat is that for the initial function (the echo statement) to work, it needs to run the function (in your code, it is moo() ) prior to outputting the initial echo statement.

This is no different to the following example:

```
echo number_format(get_something_from_database_which_is_a_number());
```

You want the function `get_something_from_database_which_is_a_number()` to return the value prior to the `number_format()` function to then format it nicely.

If you use a `return` statement, the function itself will run, but then `return` your string back to the initial function call (in your case an echo) statement.

Comment: Why does the order of parsing behave differently while using `echo` and `return`?

Comment: It doesn't, but the function itself doesn't echo anything - it just returns a string, which is then concatinated, and only then echoed (instead of having the function `echo` by itself when evaluated).

Comment: Its not the order of parsing but rather the order of execution - `echo 'hello ' . moo()` must first concat `'hello ' . moo()` which calls `moo()` which outputs 'Sam'. Then `echo 'hello ' . moo();` outputs and since `moo()` returns nothing it will output "Samhello "